# How to see documentation of inbuilt functions on Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I recently researched about finding documentation of any inbuilt `python library's` function within a `cell` of `Jupyter Notebook`. Any suggestion how I can access the documentation?. I know keyboard shortcut which is `shift + tab`, and with 4 times `shift + tab`, whole documentation with example pops up. I am just wondering the usual way, apart from shortcut.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The documentation comes from the docstring in the Python code.

You can see it by calling [help](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#help), and the `__doc__` attribute returns the string.

Taking the built-in `filter` as example:

```
# Displays the documentation for filter function
help(filter)
# Obtains the string of the documentation.
docstring = filter.__doc__
```

Comment: thanks, I wanted to know documentation as well as syntax to use. Anyways, thanks

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/